# Xcode - error in simulator on iPad (but not iPhone) accessing CoreData

Tags: ipad, core-data, xcode6, ios-simulator

My app fails with a DataCore error 9999 when I simulate an iPad but not when I simulate an iPhone. When I run the app on an iPad there is no error.

The simulator is using the same database on my desktop and I have rebuilt it several times.

Is this a bug in the simulator?

Here is the error code:

```
2015-08-16 12:07:19.750 CREW Emergency Preparedness[1195:59803] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/patriciawarwick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A1F21642-DA91-4510-9517-FC2A2756FF26/data/Containers/Data/Application/65B75062-9C98-42AA-954F-25EEC7CAA8BC/Documents/CREWData.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x7c4cb030 {metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    Notes = <cdf25e0b 15955be0 b8714aa0 675ddcb3 caa5de75 7f257d1a ca6a64e3 97791f2a>;
    Section = <78490b89 a642322e 42bbdceb 4bb3f099 6331bf84 7db3c909 cfd99469 3f3954b5>;
    Switch = <3fff52c1 6964f42e 7c8d7298 13c8cc76 8f676a2b 32a6b00f 872effa1 fb12c1bc>;
    Tips = <1946e123 3376ba49 c56b4d8d 01d1b5a7 fdec6cc0 0f632339 0f60618b 4eee6851>;
    View = <c1c09b2c 4d0cbeca 4c4b347e 5df34739 8c88d1a2 c84f1e97 f7ae7fea 5c777ab9>;
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "D4450E7A-343A-4DBA-9A45-71201155E63E";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with userInfo dictionary {
metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        Notes = <cdf25e0b 15955be0 b8714aa0 675ddcb3 caa5de75 7f257d1a ca6a64e3 97791f2a>;
        Section = <78490b89 a642322e 42bbdceb 4bb3f099 6331bf84 7db3c909 cfd99469 3f3954b5>;
        Switch = <3fff52c1 6964f42e 7c8d7298 13c8cc76 8f676a2b 32a6b00f 872effa1 fb12c1bc>;
        Tips = <1946e123 3376ba49 c56b4d8d 01d1b5a7 fdec6cc0 0f632339 0f60618b 4eee6851>;
        View = <c1c09b2c 4d0cbeca 4c4b347e 5df34739 8c88d1a2 c84f1e97 f7ae7fea 5c777ab9>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "D4450E7A-343A-4DBA-9A45-71201155E63E";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
};
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
 }
 2015-08-16 12:07:19.751 CREW Emergency Preparedness[1195:59803] Unresolved error Optional(Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo=0x7c17c300 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x7c4cb050 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.}), Optional([NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x7c4cb030 {metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    Notes = <cdf25e0b 15955be0 b8714aa0 675ddcb3 caa5de75 7f257d1a ca6a64e3 97791f2a>;
    Section = <78490b89 a642322e 42bbdceb 4bb3f099 6331bf84 7db3c909 cfd99469 3f3954b5>;
    Switch = <3fff52c1 6964f42e 7c8d7298 13c8cc76 8f676a2b 32a6b00f 872effa1 fb12c1bc>;
    Tips = <1946e123 3376ba49 c56b4d8d 01d1b5a7 fdec6cc0 0f632339 0f60618b 4eee6851>;
    View = <c1c09b2c 4d0cbeca 4c4b347e 5df34739 8c88d1a2 c84f1e97 f7ae7fea 5c777ab9>;
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "D4450E7A-343A-4DBA-9A45-71201155E63E";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.])
```

Comment: There might be some target-specific data leftover from the previous build.  If you clean (shift-cmd-k) before you execute the test, will it work?

Comment: I routinely run clean when something like this happens and it didn't help.

Comment: Forgot to mention that i reinstalled Xcode and it did not help.

Comment: Odd.  Well can you please file a radar with a sample project (http://bugreport.apple.com) and report back the radar number?

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference but this is a Universal app

Comment: Did you also delete the app from the iPad Simulator?

Comment: Being universal shouldn't make a difference.  The app will get updated upon reinstall, so that won't be an issue.  If you can provide a sample project failing like this (either in radar or hosted somewhere publicly so others can help too), that would be best.

Comment: Good point @Mundi. I did not think to reset the emulator ( I thought reinstalling the app would do that). Having done so the app now works as expected. Thank you very much.

Comment: If that is the case, then something must have gone wrong during the previous install.  Unfortunately, erasing like you did has now destroyed all relevant logs.  Please try to reproduce and figure out what the cause is or provide more specific steps for reproduction.

Comment: @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia - are you referring to my comment about resetting the emulator of something else. I had been working with that version of Xcode 6.4 since it came out with our problem until this morning I zipped the app folder when I was going to submit it to Apple. Would there be any useful info there?

Comment: OK, I added an answer that you can accept for the benefit of others reading this question.

Comment: @PatriciaW Given that the issue is "fixed" when you erase the simulated device, I suspect there is some stale state.  We'd need good reproduction steps from you.  Please figure out what you need to do to reproduce the issue from a clean slate.

Comment: @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia I have no idea what caused the problem so I doubt I will be able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the app from the iPad Simulator or reset the Simulator. That usually takes care of such problems during the development workflow.